# How do I rewrite this URL in NGINX?

Tags: php, regex, nginx, url, url-rewriting

I've just switched from Apache to NGINX, and I want to make the following URL work:
https://foo.bar/script/example-242

My folder structure is the following:
`/test/script.php`

Here is what I used to do in Apache, which worked like a charm:
`RewriteRule ^script/(.*)-([0-9]+) test/script.php?title=$1&id=$2`

Here is what I tried in NGINX:

```
location = /script/ 
{
    rewrite ^script/(.*)-([0-9]+)/?$ /test/script.php?title=$1&id=$2 break;
}
```

Tried removing slashes at the beginning, read through multiple articles and guides without success.

Comment: Try `^/script` at the start of the regex. You might also want to get rid of the `$` at the end of the regex, since you're not anchoring it like that in the apache version.

Comment: @Sammitch Sadly didn't fix the issue, still giving me a 404.

Comment: see: https://serverfault.com/a/333059

Comment: @Sammitch Thank you, spotted the issue. The equal sign in location was the issue.